# How do I show the TTS Preference Activity Settings Screen, which intent Do I need to call

Tags: android, android-intent, text-to-speech

I have implemented the TTS support for reading the Text Strings in my Application, and that works just fine.
What I want to achieve is , that the user is able to Open the Preferences for TTS and can make changes according to his/her wish.

I know there has to be some intent call that is required to be made to open the Settings Screen, but I am not able to find any thing related to it.

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Do I have to implement the whole preference screen or is it possible to open the Existing preference screen of TTS settings, anyone?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found out,

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

This seems to work just perfectly to bring on the TTS Settings screen.
Hope this helps someone.