# How to open TTS settings with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open the systems TextToSpeech settings page from within my app from within my preference activity.  I am able to open sound setting page but cannot figure out how to open the TTS settings. I also tried these two answers

[how to show up the settings for text to speech in my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160447/how-to-show-up-the-settings-for-text-to-speech-in-my-app)

[How do I show the TTS Preference Activity Settings Screen, which intent Do I need to call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749495/how-do-i-show-the-tts-preference-activity-settings-screen-which-intent-do-i-nee)

```
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Sound Settings"
    android:summary="Adjust sound settings">
   <Preference
    android:key="sound"
    android:title="Sound settings"
    android:summary="Change systems sound settings">
    <intent

         android:action="android.settings.SOUND_SETTINGS"
/>
    </Preference>
</PreferenceCategory>
```

This is on the samsung galaxy 10.1.